# Run specify app which installed in phone

Tags: android

i want to create an app with function : when i click button,an app that i installed will run (example [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tunein.player&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInR1bmVpbi5wbGF5ZXIiXQ..) )

I wrote code using getInstalledApplications (button is aupeo),but don't know how to call app,please help me

```
aupeo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

                Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);   
                if (intent != null)  {
                  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                  startActivity(intent);  
                }          
                }


        }

    });
```

Comment: visit the provided link please. all instructions are there.

Comment: Ok,i'm reading :) can you help me for this problem?

Comment: app you want to start is your app of third party app ?

Answer (score 0):

try as by checking if package name contains your application package name or not:

```
aupeo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {
  final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  List<ApplicationInfo> packages = 
                  pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

  for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
   if(packageInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().
                   contains("tunein".toLowerCase())){

     Intent intent = 
                pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);   
      if (intent != null)  {
       intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
       startActivity(intent);  
    }  
 }        
   }

 }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to launch a third party app is described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200710235813/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/launching-other-application-using-code.html). Code from the example:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("your.package.name", 
                                           "your.package.name.your.Class");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity( intent);
```

If the app you specify in the intent does not exist on the phone, I believe it throws an exception - see ρяσѕρєя K's answer for figuring out if the application exists on the phone.